# JSON to django object

Tags: python, json, django, api

I am trying to assign a JSON POST request to object but it is giving me following error:

```
          "Key 'email' not found in <QueryDict: {}>"
```

My code(using django rest framework):

```
        @api_view(['POST'])
          def login_views(request):
             if request.method == 'POST':
             email =  request.POST['email']
             result = email
             return HttpResponse(result)
```

JSON request:

```
     [{
       "email":"example@example.com"
     }]
```

Please help, new in django :)

I changed my code to:

```
      @api_view(['POST'])
          def login_views(request):
             if request.method == 'POST':
             email =  request.DATA['email']
             result = email
             return HttpResponse(result)
```

Again the following error:

```
     list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: print request.POST and paste it here! I'll try my best to help you!

Comment: I print the value of request.POST it gives ""Key 'email' not found in <QueryDict: {}>""

Comment: Comment out the line
`email =  request.DATA['email']`
Your print statement isnt working because of that.

Comment: yup that line is commented out.

Comment: write this 
`print request.POST`
You have not indexed the code properly. You should include a tab indent for all the lines that should be inside if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're using Django REST framework, right? In order to access your json post data you must use request.DATA [according to docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests): it will let you access the post parsed data. So, since your json:

```
 [{
   "email":"example@example.com"
 }]
```

is an array in json (and a list on python -notice the []) of objects you must access it this way:

```
email = request.DATA[0]["email"]
```

By the way, the error:

```
list indices must be integers, not str
```

means that request.DATA is an list, so you can't access it like a dict using str keys (request.DATA["email"]).